# Display image from form generated url

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form that allows the user to take an image. On the Response report this shows up as a URL linking to the image that was taken.
I would like to create a report page that would display that image as a part of the report and not just show the URL.
I have tried using the Image function in conjunction with a vlookup to get the URL from the cell in the report but I am getting a Parse error.
Is there a way to get the URL from the Responses sheet and have it display as the image?

Comment: `I have a form that allows the user to take an image.` I'm sorry, I don't understand this. Are you talking about a Google Form? You say that the user can "TAKE" an image" - how do they do this? I know that a user can "upload" an image, but I'm not familiar with how they can "take" an image.